# How to change Ember-Data PUT request expected server response

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data

I am using

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 1.12.1
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 1.13.4
DEBUG: jQuery            : 2.1.4
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

My server API replies to PUT request with just an ID of updated object, example of this response:

```
{
  data:[123],
  meta{total:1},
  errors:[]
}
```

How to change ember-data configuration to allow such an object?
AFAIK ember-data expects whole sent object in a response.
Thanks

## Resolution:

```
import DS from "ember-data";
export default DS.Store.extend({

    /**
     * @tampered _super
     * @param internalModel
     * @param dataArg
     */
    didSaveRecord: function (internalModel, dataArg) {
        var data;
        if (dataArg && dataArg.data && dataArg.data.id && dataArg.data.id !== 'undefined' && Ember.typeOf(dataArg.data.id) !== 'undefined') {
            data = dataArg.data;
        }
        if (data) {
            // normalize relationship IDs into records
            this._backburner.schedule("normalizeRelationships", this, "_setupRelationships", internalModel, internalModel.type, data);
            this.updateId(internalModel, data);
        }

        //We first make sure the primary data has been updated
        //TODO try to move notification to the user to the end of the runloop
        internalModel.adapterDidCommit(data);
    },


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What serializer are you using? With JSON API you could try something along the lines of:

```
export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

  normalizeUpdateRecordResponse(store, clazz, payload) {
    payload.data = {
      id: payload.data[0]
    }
    return payload;
  }
})
```

There's more info here: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html

Comment: I use DS.RESTSerializer